# show all records which contain the latest edited version

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have a table with students names, auto increased `NR` record, but on each edit of the record, a new one is created copying the `NR` to the `ID` field.
But when I try to group the ID records when MAX(`NR`) it shows me the max number of that ID but when I ask for the remaining of the rocord, it doesn't show me that last record of that group of ID's in

```
SELECT MAX(`NR`) AS 'mNr',`NR`,`ID`,`Name1`,`Name3`,`Gender`
  FROM `Kids`  GROUP BY `ID`
```

This produces results like:

```
mNr NR  ID  Name1   Name3   Gender
252 1   1   Alice   Carper  f
179 2   2   Dorah   Fisher  f
189 3   3   Racheal King    f
173 4   4   Frank   Smith   m
192 5   5   Patrick Fay m
305 6   6   Gloria  Sing    f
299 7   7   Bridget Young   f
```

But as you can see, the query shows the highest edit NR, but then continues to give the lowest of the rest of the record, not the record details belonging to that lastest NR...
What am I doing wrong?
This is the sample data:

```
NR  ID  Name1   Name3   Gender
1   1   Alice   Achand  f
2   2   Dorah   Achieng f
3   3   Racheal Achieng f
4   4   Francisca   Adikin  f
5   5   Patrick Adilu   m
6   6   Gloria  Ajwang  f
7   7   Bridget Aketch  f
130 5   Patrick Adilu   m
129 4   Francisca   Adikin  f
128 2   Dorah   Achieng f
153 4   Francisca   Adikin  f
173 4   Francisca   Adikin  f
179 2   Dorah   Achieng f
189 3   Racheal Achieng f
192 5   Patrick Adilu   m
252 1   Alice   Wor f
299 7   Bridget Aketch  f
305 6   Gloria  Ajwang  f
```

Comment: Can you show the sample data as it is and the desired outcome for the query? Right now it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps without knowing it, you are using an arcane feature of MySQL.  MySQL allows you to include columns in the `select` statement of an aggregation query that are not in aggregation functions or in the `group by` clause.  The engine puts in *arbitrary* values for these columns.

The correct way to do what you want is with a join:

```
SELECT k.*
FROM `Kids` k join
     (select id, max(nr) as maxnr
      from kids
      group by id
     ) m
     on k.id = m.id and nr = maxnr;
```

Here is the explicit explanation in the documentation:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

which you can read in more detail [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: Great, it works!
I have been struggling with this for the last 3 days.
You are a live saver ;-)

Comment: @user2811590 if you feel this is the correct answer please upvote and mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Although @Gordon Linoff's answer is technically correct, using [sub-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) may be more resource and time consuming on large data sets.

Depending on the case, I would usually separate the data into two tables `students` and `student_details` where

`students`'s table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    student_id  INTEGER       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

The idea of this table is to create a unique number for the student and store any other student data that you may not want to save in the revisions.

`student_details`'s table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE student_details (
    revision_id  INTEGER      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    student_id   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    first_name   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    gender       VARCHAR(1),
    is_history   BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

And this table stores the actual data of the student. When the data for a certain student is updated, you just need to update the `is_history` column to `true` for the records of that student. Then, when selecting your student data, you'd simply use `SELECT student_details.* FROM students LEFT JOIN student_details ON (student_details.student_id = students.student_id AND student_details.is_history = false)`. This will always return the latest revision of a student's detail.

**Inserting a new student**

1. Insert a student 
    `INSERT INTO students(student_id) VALUES('');`
2. Get the lasted insert id 
    `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` (let's say it returns 1 for the sake of this example)
3. Insert the student details 
    `INSERT INTO student_details(student_id, first_name, last_name, gender) VALUES('1', 'Alice', 'Carper', 'f')`

**Updating an existing student (let's say student_id = 1)**

1. Set all previous student_detail "revisions" as "history": 
    `UPDATE student_details SET is_history = true WHERE student_details.student_id = 1 AND is_history = false`
2. Add the new revision: 
    `INSERT INTO student_details(student_id, first_name, last_name, gender) VALUES('1', 'Alice', 'Achand', 'f')`

**Getting a student and his latest student details**

`SELECT student_details.* FROM students LEFT JOIN student_details ON (student_details.student_id = students.student_id AND student_details.is_history = false)`